# Statically build C++ in VS19 with external dlls

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++ project in 2019 that I am trying to build statically. I am currently using the MT option. However when I test my executable in a VM environment, it says i'm missing some 3rd party DLLs. My question is how am I able to statically include these 3rd party DLLs as part of my build?

Comment: Which DLLs? There may not be a static library for them

Comment: If you know what those 3:rd party DLL's are, then you need to contact those 3:rd parties to see if they provide static libraries. If they are open-source projects then you have to check their project pages to see if it's available for download already or if it can be built from source. If it's not available then you can't link with them statically and have to include them as DLL's with your package.

Comment: They are mysql dlls. I am currently linking the the static .lib in the Linker > Input, but starting up the C++ application is asking for associated dlls. 

I can add these dlls as a part of my build, but these dlls reference dlls found in the C++ redistributable so I get an error on those as well.

Comment: The `.lib` file you link with is probably not the static library, but a DLL stub library.

Comment: The `/MT` option applies to C++ Runtime DLLs, it has no effect on 3rd-party DLLs. There is probably a static MySQL client available. However, keep in mind that the MySQL Connector/C is GPL-licensed, which makes your entire program GPL too (i.e. open-source). It might be better to use the alternative MariaDB Connector/C, which is LGPL-licensed. However, LGPL-licensed software is normally distributed as a DLL so as to clearly separate it from the rest of the software (only in that case it can remain closed-source).

Comment: My advice is to generate an installer package for your application.

Comment: All great advice, thanks guys!